# Use single activity multiple times

Tags: android

I an creating a android quiz, in which I am giving 4 options in form of button. I want that when user select correct/wrong option question get change with score increment/decrement and activity remain same. How should I implement that.  Can you please show me code for that....

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use fragments in the same activity? When a question is answered, you only have to change the fragment using FragmentManager called from the container activity.
Here is a useful link: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Another approach is to dynamically change TextView and RadioButton content when the user answers.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for response,

I solved my problem by following code

In activity A:

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

            score++;

            Intent i=new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);

            startActivity(i);
         }
     });
```

So whenever user click on button, score incremented, and same activity again called....